# Getting Error like TikTokApi object has no attribute get_Video_No_Watermark

Tags: python, api, selenium, screen-scraping, tiktok

I am using Tiktok libaray to download the video wihtout watermark and saved it inside my laptop but script generates an error like
`AttributeError: 'TikTokApi' object has no attribute 'get_Video_No_Watermark'`

Is there anyway that we can resolve this issue or can we get an alternate way to download the video without watermark using python script.

```
url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/@wigcenter/video/7090914793049034010'
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
api = TikTokApi()
video_url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/@wigcenter/video/7090914793049034010'
data = api.get_Video_No_Watermark(video_url, return_bytes=1, language='en', proxy=None, custom_verifyFp="")
with open("tiktok.mp4", 'wb') as output:
    output.write(data)
```

TikTopApi Version:  **TikTokApi-5.1.1**

Answer (score 0):

This error means that python-playwright or selenium is not launching correctly. What I did is

1.`Check the version of your chrome Right upper corner -> help -> About Google Chrome`

2.`Download the chromedriver from chromedriver`

3.`let your API find the driver`

```
api = TikTokApi.get_instance(use_selenium=True, executablePath="/path/to/chromedriver")
```